# What can headshot enemies?

Tags: overwatch

Are there specific weapons that can headshot enemies, or can all attacks headshot enemies, including melee attacks? Can all hero abilities headshot enemies, such as Genji's Slash Dash if aimed correctly?

I would also like to know, besides what can headshot enemies, which of those weapons have the biggest leniency in terms of getting headshot. For example, with hanzo, you can aim close to the head and it will still count as a headshot; is his Storm Bow the most lenient in the game in terms of how far you can stray from a player's head and still get headshots, or are there other weapons that allow for even bigger cheesing?

Comment: The second part of the question seems like a duplicate of the one you just asked about who has the biggest head hitbox.

Comment: @DCShannon Projectiles have a hitbox, some projectiles I believe have bigger hitboxes than others. You're confusing the term hitbox with head hitbox, the two can factor with each other but are both separate entities (projectile hitbox and head hitbox)

Comment: Ah okay, the other question is asking about the character's hitbox, here you're asking about the size of the projectile. Could be clearer, but I got ya.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All weapons with the exception of Pharah, McCree's secondary, Junkrat, Mei's primary, Reinhardt, Winston, Zarya, Ana (on friend or foe), and Symmetra can headshot. Damage reflected by Genji can headshot as well as the initial arrows for each Hanzo's abilities (though the scattered projectiles and dragon themselves cannot). Roadhog's Whole Hog ultimate can headshot. Other abilities and all melee attacks cannot headshot.

Comment: so even if I land a Zarya alt-fire on an enemy's head it will not hs, correct?

Comment: No, it will not. I haven't gotten headshots with Zarya before, though I'll probably go into training mode later today to double-check.

Comment: Zarya's primary can't headshot? That's surprising and confusing. It's a tight beam. Why wouldn't it head shot?

Comment: And Junkrat's grenades are small projectiles like Hanzo's arrows but also can't headshot. I imagine it has to do with game balance. With enough energy under her belt, Zarya can easily take apart most characters. Having double-damage headshots on top of that might make her too strong.

Comment: Can Reaper's shotguns and Roadhog's scrap gun headshot? I'd be extremely surprised if they could, given that it would let those characters one-shot an average-health hero at close range.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Yes, Reaper and Roadhog can headshot. In fact, this is what makes Reaper such a good tank-killer, repeated headshots with his shotguns chews them up.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish One-shotting squishy heroes at close range is basically the entire reason for Roadhog to exist.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Can't he one-shot them without landing a headshot, though? Or have I just been accidentally headshot-ing every other time i hook someone?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish The absolute squishiest (aka Zenyatta and Tracer) will die without a headshot at point blank, but otherwise generally no. Generally you tend to get at least a few of the scrap gun's pellets to headshot because of its spread, and because hooking people leaves their head close to your reticle a lot of the time.

Comment: I believe McCree's right click can't headshot either.

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich I'm fairly certain that I remember getting sound effect and larger hit ping for headshots with McCree's right-click, but I'll go and test it out.